# Hide status bar on android

Tags: android, statusbar

I am trying to hide the status bar. I have tried the following things.
This is for phones. I realize tablets can be different. It does hide the status bar when the layout has a bottom Tab. any ideas?

```
android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"
```

In the `Manifest.XML` I have added the above code.

And in the `onCreate()` I have added the followingin the right place:

```
requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
// hide statusbar of Android
// could also be done later
getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
        WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
```

Comment: what does the mean of bottom tab ?

Comment: I would like to hide the status bar (where the battery indicator and stuff is) my Home screen has a Tabbed layout and Full screen hiding the status bar works there. but in other screens without a Bottom tab bar it doesn't work

Comment: Ok seems to be working now. Full reboot of computer and now it's working?

Comment: doesn't work for me, using kitkat on Nexus5. All it does is render my main activity white background to transparent

Comment: you can find the answer [here][1] . it works like charm. Hope it helps


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25284233/prevent-status-bar-for-appearing-android-modified/25397029?noredirect=1#comment50756233_25397029