# How we can disable navigation soft buttons home,recent

Tags: android, lockscreen

Im working on lockscreen in android
How we can disable navigation soft buttons, have tried all the ways, systemoverlay
but its doesnt work, on pressing home button its kill the service and activity.

Comment: Have a look at this https://github.com/Joisar/LockScreenApp/blob/master/LockScreenApp/src/com/mehuljoisar/lockscreen/LockScreenActivity.java

Comment: The solution only works on devices with hard home key @billynomates you can't disable for home button in 4.0+

Answer (score 2):

1. **back button** can be controlled by overriding the onbackpressed() method.
2. Homebutton can controlled by making your application a launch.

> ```
>  <intent-filter>
>         <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
>         <category android:name="android.intent.category.HOME" />
>         <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
>     </intent-filter>
> ```

above code shows intentfilter for creating an launcher. For more info google about making an app a launcher app.

3. the recent app button can be controlled by bringing your app 
   by using **moveTaskToFront** in your onpause function of the activity(*This works only in and after honeycomb*).

add the below code in your

> ActivityManager activityManager = (ActivityManager) getApplicationContext()
>                       .getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
>
> activityManager.moveTaskToFront(getTaskId(),
>                     ActivityManager.MOVE_TASK_NO_USER_ACTION);

Answer (score 0):

You cannot override the home button on version 4.0+
This is made for security purpose.

However, you can create a service that shows a window that handles all touch events.
Take a look at the best answer at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4481226/creating-a-system-overlay-window-always-on-top)

You may also look at some 'App Lock' applications, cause they use the same technique.

But this way doesn't work completely. On some devices, it is possible to open NotificationBar above your service.

There is also another way, and it can override the home button, but does not work for Recent.

You should create an application that will be considered on device as a Launcher Application, but will look like a Locker.
Now, when the user unlocks the device, your application starts the actual Launcher Application.

Comment: ya thats awsome its really work like a real lock screen.. Thanks