# Too many clicks on a layout

Tags: android, click, frame, ondraw, skip

I have a layout which consists some buttons. If I tap the buttons very fast (like a crazy)

I've got this error:
Choreographer: Skipped X frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.

These buttons have no specific background or click/tap listener.

I think the onDraw method of these buttons interrupt the main thread too long.

Can I use a flag or something to prevent this? So I would like to send a message to the Choreographer/Looper to skip all event not just some frame.

If I use a layout with complex hierarchy and I tap buttons with listeners the application freezes. Loading screen/dialog it' not an option for me... Any idea?

this is the layout of my fragment: (it's inside a FrameLayout)

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/second_line"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="96dp"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:weightSum="6"
    android:padding="0dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="0dip"
    android:layout_marginRight="0dip"
    android:layout_marginTop="0dip"
    android:layout_marginBottom="0dip">
    <Button
        android:layout_width="161dp"
        android:layout_height="96dp"
        android:id="@+id/indicator3"
        android:padding="0dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="0dip"
        android:layout_marginRight="0dip"
        android:layout_marginTop="0dip"
        android:layout_marginBottom="0dip"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"/>
    <Button
        android:layout_width="161dp"
        android:layout_height="96dp"
        android:id="@+id/indicator4"
        android:padding="0dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="0dip"
        android:layout_marginRight="0dip"
        android:layout_marginTop="0dip"
        android:layout_marginBottom="0dip"
        android:scaleType="fitXY" />
    <Button
        android:layout_width="161dp"
        android:layout_height="96dp"
        android:id="@+id/indicator5"
        android:padding="0dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="0dip"
        android:layout_marginRight="0dip"
        android:layout_marginTop="0dip"
        android:layout_marginBottom="0dip"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"/>
    <Button
        android:layout_width="161dp"
        android:layout_height="96dp"
        android:id="@+id/indicator6"
        android:padding="0dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="0dip"
        android:layout_marginRight="0dip"
        android:layout_marginTop="0dip"
        android:layout_marginBottom="0dip"
        android:scaleType="fitXY" />
    <Button
        android:layout_width="161dp"
        android:layout_height="96dp"
        android:id="@+id/indicator7"
        android:padding="0dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="0dip"
        android:layout_marginRight="0dip"
        android:layout_marginTop="0dip"
        android:layout_marginBottom="0dip"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"/>
    <Button
        android:layout_width="161dp"
        android:layout_height="96dp"
        android:id="@+id/indicator8"
        android:padding="0dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="0dip"
        android:layout_marginRight="0dip"
        android:layout_marginTop="0dip"
        android:layout_marginBottom="0dip"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Are you using emulator?

Comment: plz show layout code

Comment: I run in a HP Slate 10 Plus, not emulator.

Comment: @StanislavBondar Edited the question with the layout code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I find the solution. It's a kiosk application, so I'm disable the notifocation bar by this post: [Prevent status bar for appearing android (modified)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25284233/prevent-status-bar-for-appearing-android-modified?answertab=active#tab-top)

Every click triggered an event to add a view to window. So I check that the view already added to the window or not. It's solved my problem.