# How to block Android keys for public Tablet?

Tags: android, tablet, kiosk

I want to disable Android keys. I developed an application for tablets. But I want to disable tablet or android keys. In addition,customer have to use only my single application.

I am aware of kiosk but still have some problem. Could you help me please ?

[image]

Comment: check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17549478/how-to-disable-home-and-other-system-buttons-in-android

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Kiosk mode in Android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2068084/kiosk-mode-in-android)

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for something like site kiosk mode:

- Check here: [Kiosk mode in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2068084/kiosk-mode-in-android)
- or here: http://www.andreas-schrade.de/2015/02/16/android-tutorial-how-to-create-a-kiosk-mode-in-android/
- and here: [Prevent status bar for appearing android (modified)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25284233/prevent-status-bar-for-appearing-android-modified)