# Unable to set screen brightness in android when I am blocking status bar expansion using WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_SYSTEM_ERROR overlay

Tags: android

I am developing Kiosk android app where I am blocking android status bar expansion using `WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_SYSTEM_ERROR` overlay.

Issue with this fix is I am unable to change screen brightness. To update brightness I am using following code.

```
if (mWindow == null) mWindow = getWindow();
WindowManager.LayoutParams layoutParams = mWindow.getAttributes();
layoutParams.screenBrightness = brightness;
mWindow.setAttributes(layoutParams);
```

To disable status bar expansion I referred [Prevent status bar for appearing android (modified)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25284233/prevent-status-bar-for-appearing-android-modified)

Comment: Any help ? Unable to handle both feature together.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With SYSTEM_ERROR overlay, it is not possible to handle screen brightness. So I am blocking status bar only when onWindowFocusChanged, and blocking for only 3 minutes. Then removing overlay so that I am able to handle screen brightness.